# Grant write permission to a Perl script when it is called from a shell script regardless of user

Tags: perl, permissions

I have a function in a Bash shell script that is called upon start-up of the script.  The function performs a sort on a data file, then calls a Perl script which checks to see if a backup of the script and data files needs to be performed, if so the Perl script makes backups and then compresses all backups in the backup directory.  The Bash and Perl scripts work fine when I run the Bash script, but other users are getting errors returned from the Perl script that says they do not have permission to write the files.
How do I elevate the permissions of the Perl script so that any user can write to the directory?  I have the directory where the files are to be written with read write permissions for all users, but the users still get this error upon opening the Bash script.

> tar: /absolute/path/to/file/location/filename.tar.gz: Cannot >open: Permission >denied
> tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

this is the Function in the Bash script calling the Perl script

```
sourcefile(){
# sorts the script source file in alphabetical order each time the script runs.
sort /absolute/path/to/data-file.txt -o /absolute/path/to/data-file.txt
#
# Calls a perl script to run backups of the script and data files.
/absolute/path/to/location/./scrpt_maint.prl
#       
}
```

This is the Perl script which creates the backups

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
##
use strict; 
use warnings;
## 
use File::stat;
use Time::localtime;
use Time::Local;
use File::Copy;
##
my $source = "/PATH/PATH/PATH/backup/FILENAME.sh.bak";
my $today = time;
my $modtime = (stat($source)->mtime);
my $interval = 86400; #- =24 hours in seconds
my $delta = ($today - $modtime);
#
# my $interval = 30; #- =30 second intervals for testing
# 
my $SRC_SCRIPTS = "/PATH/PATH/PATH/";
my $TARGET_SCPTS = "/PATH/PATH/PATH/backup/";
#
###############################

if ( $delta >= $interval ) {
                &backup;
                system "tar -czf     /PATH/PATH/PATH/backup/compressed/FILENAME.tar.gz -C /     /PATH/PATH/PATH/backup/compressed";


}
#
sub backup {
#
opendir(my $SCRIPTS, $SRC_SCRIPTS ) || die "can't opendir $SRC_SCRIPTS: $!"    ;

my @SCRIPTS = readdir($SCRIPTS);

foreach my $t (@SCRIPTS)
{ 
        if( -f "$SRC_SCRIPTS/$t" ) {
                copy "$SRC_SCRIPTS/$t", "$TARGET_SCPTS/$t.bak" || warn "Copy     of $t to $TARGET_SCPTS failed: $!";
                }
}

}
#
exit;
```

I am by no means a Shell or Perl expert, so if these are sloppy or not best practice, that is why.  I am not the admin and do not have root access to the linux server.  I am writing this in  Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4

Thanks

Comment: What's the permissions on the directory structure `/PATH/PATH/PATH/backup/compressed/FILENAME.tar.gz`? Because what is happening here is your script is bailing out on that `tar` command, which implies your perl is fine.

Comment: drwxrw-rw-  2 USERNAME ncs  4096 May 14 12:46 compressed

Comment: OK. Try setting`a+x` on that directory. I think that'll be the problem.

Comment: Sorry Sobrique, I missread your question.  The permissions on the Filename.tar.gz were, -rw-r--r-- I just chmod'ed them to -rw-rw-rw-.  I had tried to add the write permission to the /compressed/ folder, thinking the files in the folder would inherit the permission, is this not the case?

Comment: No, it's not. Permissions on a folder don't propagate automatically. Write permission on a directory is being able to 'edit the directory list'. But you also need `x` permissions on the directory - `x`  denotes executable on a file, but 'can access' on a directory. (sort of)

Comment: Sobrique,  I added a+x on the folders, and a+w on all the files within, and the script is running without errors and the backups are working correctly!  Thank You!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, based on the comments your problem was:

```
drwxrw-rw- 2 USERNAME ncs 4096 May 14 12:46 compressed
```

The permissions on the `Filename.tar.gz` were, `-rw-r--r--` I just chmod'ed them to `-rw-rw-rw`

Solution was:

```
chmod a+x compressed
chmod a+rw Filename.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

why would several users have to run this backup process? ... i'm thinking based on previous comments the problem is indeed on the result file `compressed/FILENAME.tar.gz`

the permission of your compress directory is `drwxrw-rw-` which is fine => anybody can write a file in it. the file that would be created (let's say by user1) will be owned by user1 and have the permission defined by `umask` setting for user1, generally:

```
[~]=> umask -S
u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx
```

then if another user (let's say user2) is running the script, this file already created and cannot be changed

Several ways to solve the problem

1. you can add a `chmod 777 compressed/FILENAME.tar.gz` after your tar command. Not my preference cause, anybody can remove by mistake this file.
2. restrict this script to be run only by one user
3. or use a changing filename based on time like `FILENAME20150514-0830.tgz` and then organize a cleanup of older files to keep only the last n backups (would be a great idea)

I would go for 3, if you have a space constraints, you can always say n=1

The additional advantage is also that whenever your process is crashing you always have some valid backups